# Why do I have no permission by this settings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to do an INSERT on an table. If I do a normal INSERT I got the error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'mytable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

So I append the statement to

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON

INSERT INTO mytable (myCols) VALUES(myVals)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON
```

If I execute this statement I get the following error:

> Cannot find the object "mytable" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Additional, if I go in the user mappings I get the following alert:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> One or more databases are inaccessible and will not be displayed in list

The settings for the user are this:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong, but I hope you can help me to find a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure you are executing it in the same database ?

Comment: Have you tried `dbo.`MyTable ? Or maybe it is in another schema ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with <schema>.mytable but it doesn't work.

Comment: It does not look like a security problem to me, one of those 3 statements is failing to find that table. So I think you either typed it wrong, you are in the wrong schema, or in the wrong database.

Comment: okay. Additional, if I go in the user mappings I get the following alert: ```TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

One or more databases are inaccessible and will not be displayed in list.

------------------------------ ```

Comment: I would edit your question and put this relevant data there, certainly when this is about the database you are trying this in

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` requires that you ["... own the table or have ALTER permission on the table"](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql#permissions), merely being able to insert data is not enough. (This is a rather silly requirement, but then a lot of T-SQL security is a bit silly.)